# How to upload images to just created directory/subfolder

Tags: php, file-upload, subdirectory

The code below allows to name and create a new folder in the "albums" directory and also uploads the images in the same directory. Can you tell me how to upload the images directly in the new subfolder that i've created. 
This is the form:

```
    <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" 
    method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
 Album name :  <input type="text" name="textfield" id="textfield"> 
 Upload image: <input type="file" name="fileup" /><br/>
  <input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Augsupieladet">
</form>
```

And the php code

```
<?php
$get_folder = $_POST['textfield'];
mkdir ("./albums/" . $get_folder, 0777);
echo "Album created successfully";

$uploadpath = ("./albums");      //directory where the images are uploaded now
$max_size = 2000;          
$allowtype = array('bmp', 'gif', 'jpg', 'jpe', 'png', 'jpeg');        

if(isset($_FILES['fileup']) && strlen($_FILES['fileup']['name']) > 1) {
$uploadpath = $uploadpath . basename( $_FILES['fileup']['name']);       
$sepext = explode('.', strtolower($_FILES['fileup']['name']));
$type = end($sepext);       
$err = '';         

if(!in_array($type, $allowtype)) 
$err .= 'Fails: <b>'. $_FILES['fileup']['name']. 'incorrect file type.';
if($_FILES['fileup']['size'] > $max_size*1000)
$err .= 'Max size of image: '.  $max_size. ' KB.';


if($err == '') {
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['fileup']['tmp_name'], $uploadpath)) { 
echo 'Image: <b>'. basename( $_FILES['fileup']['name']). '</b> Upload succesful:';
}
else echo '<b>Upload unsuccesful.</b>';
}
else echo $err;
}
?>
```

Comment: Wow! Be careful letting a user type the folder: `../../../lols`

Comment: I should add though that you can store the path in a variable: `$path = './albums/' . $get_folder;` which you can use later in the script

Comment: Just add $get_folder to the $upload_path?

Answer (score 1):

You can't "directly" choose where files are uploaded to in PHP.  What you are wanting to do is "move" the uploaded file to the correct location.

```
<?php
$get_folder = $_POST['textfield'];

// you should clean this..
$uploadpath =  "./albums/" . $get_folder.'/';

mkdir ($uploadpath, 0777);

echo "Album created successfully";
// remove the line below. variable was set previously
//$uploadpath = ("./albums");    
$max_size = 2000;          
$allowtype = array('bmp', 'gif', 'jpg', 'jpe', 'png', 'jpeg');        

if(isset($_FILES['fileup']) && strlen($_FILES['fileup']['name']) > 1) {
    $uploadpath = $uploadpath . basename( $_FILES['fileup']['name']);       
    $sepext = explode('.', strtolower($_FILES['fileup']['name']));
    $type = end($sepext);       
    $err = '';         

    if(!in_array($type, $allowtype)) 
        $err .= 'Fails: <b>'. $_FILES['fileup']['name']. 'incorrect file type.';
    if($_FILES['fileup']['size'] > $max_size*1000)
        $err .= 'Max size of image: '.  $max_size. ' KB.';


    if($err == '') {
        if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['fileup']['tmp_name'], $uploadpath)) { 
            echo 'Image: <b>'. basename( $_FILES['fileup']['name']). '</b> Upload succesful:';
        }
        else echo '<b>Upload unsuccesful.</b>';
    }
    else echo $err;
}
?>
```

Comment: The image is still in the "albums" directory and now it adds the created new subfolder's name at the beginning of uploaded image's name. :/

Comment: I updated the code sample `$uploadpath =  "./albums/" . $get_folder.'/';`